# Arrays pushing characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

It might be a stupid question but it confused me.

```js
var text = "Hello Mr Andreas Andreas Kostakis o ala krem Andreas o pianistas o poutsopnikt\o skaraveos o Andreas";
var myName = "Andreas";
var hits = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if ( myName[0] === text[i] )
    {
        for (var j = i; j <  (myName.length + i); j++){
            hits.push(text[j]);    
         }
    }
}
for ( var i  = 0; i < hits.length; i++ )
{
  document.write(hits[i]);
}
```

The part that iam getting confused in this code is , the first loop its searching for the first character of myName string which is 'A' from the text string . When it finds it (in our example its gonna find it on the the 8th(starting from 0) iteration . Its going into another loop which we said J = I so the j is getting the value of 8 , and as long as the j which is 8 is not equal to the length of the name string + 8(i) will start pushing character from text[8] til it hits the myName + i length . My question is where hits[] array its gonna put the characters? It will start from hits[0] ? And when it finds the 'A' again its gonna continue from there? Why it doesnt overwrite the hits array when it hits to the next 'A' character ?

Comment: The `.push()` function always adds to the end of the target array. The `hits` array starts out empty, so the first character pushed becomes the first entry. After that, `.push()` always adds at the end.

Comment: Not clear! What exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Make the last loop `k` instead of `i`

Comment: @zer00ne why? is not nested or am i wrong?

Comment: It's confusing like OP's question.

Comment: 1 - to the end, 2 - yes, 3 - yes, 4 - why would it?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want this code to do?  At a glance it smacks of an over-engineered solution, but I am not really clear on the intent...

Comment: @BulentVural 1-Your comment was confusing as well. 2- Objective is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript `Array.prototype.push()` is non-destructive, just like the `concat()` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

Because the array hits[] is initialized outside of the loop. After the first loop runs, the array will already have content in it. When the second loop runs, it will just push more elements to it.
If the hits[] array was initialized inside the loop, then content will be overwritten.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1NAkcsMuwVkXvzh4OKJP?p=preview

```
var text = "Hello Mr Andreas Andreas Kostakis o ala krem Andreas o pianistas o poutsopnikt\o skaraveos o Andreas";
var myName = "Andreas";
var hits_to_not_overwrite = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if ( myName[0] === text[i] ) {
        var hits_to_overwrite = [];
        for (var j = i; j <  (myName.length + i); j++){
            hits_to_not_overwrite.push(text[j]);    
            hits_to_overwrite.push(text[j]);    
         }
    }
}

document.write("<p>No overwrite:</p>");
for (var i  = 0; i < hits_to_not_overwrite.length; i++ ) {
  document.write(hits_to_not_overwrite[i]);
}

document.write("<p>Overwrite:</p>");
for (var i  = 0; i < hits_to_overwrite.length; i++ ) {
  document.write(hits_to_overwrite[i]);
}
```